# Removing unwanted characters from coordinate field

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro

I have some data that arrives via an Excel XLSX file that I import into a feature class.  The Excel file has a field `GPS` where the users have typed in coordinates, eg `32.1357, -116.81828`, which I split into two separate fields in order to use the XYTableToPoint tool to generate the feature class.

The problem is that they're *typing* the coordinates into the field, so sometimes my coordinate has no space,  `32.1357,-116.81828`, sometimes it has no comma, `32.1357 -116.81828`, etc.  Really I guess it could be anything, until I can provide a solution that eliminates this user error potential (not an option at this point unfortunately).

Current within my UpdateCursor I'm using a series of `str.replace()` to try to eliminate the potential issues, but I believe there must be a more efficient way to do it.

```py
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_mem,["GPS","GPS_X","GPS_Y"]) as cursor:
    for gps, gps_x, gps_y in cursor:
        m_gps_y, m_gps_x = gps.replace(", ","#").replace(",","#").replace(" ","#").split("#")
        gps_x = m_gps_x
        gps_y = m_gps_y
        cursor.updateRow([gps,gps_x,gps_y])
```

How can I remove these unwanted extra characters from a field of coordinates, or extract just the coordinate values for my two new fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex `re.findall` can solve your problem. `r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"` finds all float numbers, both negative or positive. It accepts any separator.

```
regex = r"[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_mem,["GPS","GPS_X","GPS_Y"]) as cursor:
    for gps, gps_x, gps_y in cursor:
      
        matches = re.findall(regex, gps, re.MULTILINE)
        if len(matches) == 2:
            gps_x = float(matches[0])
            gps_y = float(matches[1])
            cursor.updateRow([gps,gps_x,gps_y])
        else:
            print ('Error in coordinate entry')
```